# In Atom when it try to open a html file using the package (open-in-browser) it displays the error: Error: Exited with code 4 .(OS used- Linux Ubuntu)

Tags: html, css, frontend, atom-editor, web-development-server

package used : (open-in-browsers) by *magbicaleman*

**Error: Exited with code 4**

```
Error: Exited with code 4
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/chinu/.atom/packages/open-in-browser/node_modules/opn/index.js:83:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo the error is an aspect of the package(open-in-browser) it has no whatsoever relation with the code ☺️.

Comment: Then you probably want to report this error to the github page or something